# Java Binary Tree Cloning Problem

Tags: java, clone, binary-tree

I have a Java Binary Tree with the below specification and I need to clone it.

```
public class Item {

    private final String value;
    public final Item left;
    public final Item right;

    ...

}
```

What seems to be a very simple task has me baffled in that the cloned tree must share the same cells with the original tree object rather than being copied.

However if an item were to be added to either the original or cloned tree, it must not propagate to the other tree. ie. If a new item were to be added to the original tree, it must not appear in the cloned tree and vice vera.

Also this needs to be done without recursion and without any looping construct.

So I was wondering if anyone can think of anyway to do this because I have no idea where to start?

Comment: Is this homework? If so you should add the `homework` tag. To clone a tree without recursion or looping is impossible, assuming the trees can be arbitrarily large. Could you also elaborate on "the cloned tree must share the same cells with the original tree object rather than being copied"? It sounds inconistent with "if an item were to be added to either the original or cloned tree, it must not propagate to the other tree".

Comment: well, it's not connected to your question, but why are left and right final? whenever you will want to add a new node, you will have to destroy the whole tree and build it from scratch... (or at least the path to the root) because you will have to create a new parent for the node, (since you cannot change left/right) and recursively, create a new node for each one (same reason) until you get to the root.

Comment: @amit Splay can be used to resolve this.

Comment: @OpenSauce What I meant was that the cloned tree's cells must reference the original tree so that it is 'memory efficient and fast'. What I said afterwards is also correct in that if any item were to be added to either the original or cloned tree, it must not appear in the other tree.

Comment: @OpenSauce To solve the problem, I was thinking of having the cloned 'value' variable reference the variable found in the original tree since it has been declared as final. After which creating new cells for the left and right branches and then referencing the 'value' variables found in the child items back to the corresponding original tree. So in the end, all 'values' will reference the original trees however the 'Item' objects will be new. However I cannot think of how I could do this without recursion or looping.

Comment: I guess by "cell" you mean the value field, and not an instance of `Item`. In that case, what you say should be fine.  It will still be impossible without recursion or looping though, unless there's some very clever trick I'm missing. I'd suggest Osiris76's answer.

Comment: Cannot be solved without loop or recursion. You need one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done if you set up copy on write in the structure:

```
/*in Item */
Item add(String value){
   Item item = new Item(this.value);
   if(value.compareTo(this.value)<0){
      item.left = this.left;
      item.right = this.right.add(value);
   }else{
      item.left = this.left.add(value);
      item.right = this.right;
   }
   return item;
}
```

then the cloning is only copying the root to the other tree

Answer (score 5):

```
Node cloneTree(Node root) {
        Node n1 = new Node();
        n1.value = root.value;
        cloneTree(root, n1);
        return n1;
}

void cloneTree(Node root, Node newNode) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (root.leftNode != null) {
            newNode.leftNode = new Node();
            newNode.leftNode.value = root.leftNode.value;
            cloneTree(root.leftNode, newNode.leftNode);
        }
        if (root.rightNode != null) {
            newNode.rightNode = new Node();
            newNode.rightNode.value = root.rightNode.value;
            cloneTree(root.rightNode, newNode.rightNode);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a clone method for a specific node. This method creates a new node with the value of the current node. Result of the method would be the cloned node.

In the method you could call the clone method for the right and left node recursively. The result of the calls will be set as right and left node of the cloned node. This should do the trick.

The code would look something like this

```
public Item cloneItem() {

    Item cloneLeft = left.cloneItem();
    Item cloneRight = right.cloneItem();
    return new Item(value, cloneLeft, cloneRight);
}
```

You have to check if left and/or right are set which I have left out in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` for the left and right sub tree's don't make much sense. Making them final, the tree is essentially immutable, and as such an insert operation does not make sense. Anyway, this code should hopefully warm up the thinking process.

```
public class Node {
  final String value;
  Node left;
  Node right;

  boolean copyOnWrite; //google it for more information

  public Node(String value,Node left,Node right,boolean copyOnWrite) {
    //blabla
  }

  public Node copy() { //not recursive!
    copyOnWrite = true;
    return new Node(value,left,right,true);
  }

  public Node deepCopy() { //recursive!
    return new Node(value,left.deepCopy(),right.deepCopy(),false);
  }

  public void insert(String value) {
    if (copyOnWrite) {
      copyOnWrite = false;
      left = left.deepCopy();
      right = right.deepCopy();
    }
    //normal tree insert code
  }
```

So, calling `copy()` is fast it makes a shallow copy. A `deepCopy()` is only performed when an attempt is made to modify it. Actually, there is no need to make a deep copy of the *entire* tree , but since this is homework, I leave that(how many copies are needed? What nodes become 'dirty'?) as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple straightforward answer is to make a Cell object and have the tree node reference it rather than the data of the cell within the node.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with recursion.
might still need to consider some edge cases but the logic is right.

public class CloneTree {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    tNode root=createTree();
    if(root==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    tNode newR=new tNode();
    cloneMyTree(root,newR);
    printTree(newR);



}




private static tNode cloneMyTree(tNode root, tNode newR) {
    if(root==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    tNode leftSubNode=null;
    tNode rightSubNode=null;

    if(!(root.left==null))
        {
         leftSubNode = new tNode();
          cloneMyTree(root.left, leftSubNode);
        }

    if(!(root.right==null))
    {
     rightSubNode = new tNode();
      cloneMyTree(root.right, rightSubNode);
    }

    newR.left=leftSubNode;
    newR.right=rightSubNode;
    newR.value=root.value;


    return root;




}

public static void printTree(tNode root)
{
    if(root==null)
    {
        System.out.println("NULL");
        return;
    }
    else{
    System.out.println(root.value);
    System.out.println("Left of "+root.value);
    printTree(root.left);

    System.out.println("right of "+root.value);
    printTree(root.right);
    }

}



public static tNode  createTree()
{
bTree myTree=new bTree();
myTree.root = new tNode(1);

myTree.root.left=new tNode(2);
myTree.root.left.left=new tNode(4);
myTree.root.left.right= new tNode(5);

myTree.root.right= new tNode(3);
myTree.root.right.left=new tNode(6);
myTree.root.right.right=new tNode(7);
return myTree.root;

}
```

}